# What is the Mongoose model for subdocuments pointing to another subdocument in the same collection

Tags: mongoose

I have a document of below structure with two types of subdocument. Second subdocuments refers to some of first subdocuments but not all

```
var snippet = new schema{
 data:string,
 questions:[question],
 answers:[answer]
};

var question = new schema{
  questiontext:string
}
var answers = new schema{
   answertext :string,
   questionsAnswered : []
}
```

here the 'answertext' needs to be linked to multiple questions as an answer can be valid for more than one question.

In answers schema how should I store the questions. I do not want to store  the question objects data again as it would be repeat of data and also if some questions are modified, then it needs to be modified in questionsAnswered subdocument as well. So basically I want to store the _id of questions in questionsAnswered.

what would be syntax for answer schema in mongoose? currently I have empty array, but not sure whether this is good approach

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late coming but, in case someone needs a solution...

You can do it just as you have.  But, I think you're looking for something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var question = new Schema({
  questionText: String
});

var answers = new Schema ({
  answertext: String,
  questionsAnswered : [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'question'
  }]
});
```

This will allow you to store an array of ObjectIds that reference the stored question documents.  Strictly speaking, you don't need to use ObjectId, and could, instead, store the _ids as Strings, if you had some reason to do so.

```
...
questionsAnswered : [String]
...
```

But, you would have to handle the logic yourself, converting ObjectIds to Strings, and vice versa.  For that matter, you can store the _id value of questions in a [] array, but again, you need to handle any logic/conversion yourself.